What is the simplest way of retrieving the last element of a stringstream?
I am writing a Book class as a exercise from the C++ book I am reading. I want to store the last name of an Author for sorting all of the books.
So lets say the author is named: "Albert Ein Stein"
Then only the last name "Stein" should be separated and stored. The full name is stored in a string: std::string full_name = "Albert Ein Stein"
I thought converting the full name into a stringstream and somehow retrieving only the last element of the buffer would be a good solution. Something like this:
void get_last_name (const std::string& full_name)
{
    std::stringstream stream(full_name);
    auto it = stream.end() - 1;
    std::string last_name = *it;
}

But this is invalid syntax. What is a simple way to only retieve the last element of the string buffer?

A simpler approach is probably rfind followed by substr.

You can't do that with stringstream without first extracting the underlying string, and at that point it was pointless to construct stringstream

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of the example in documentation is doing exactly what you are searching for.

@mch I was thinking the same, but while it answers OP's problem, it doesn't answer OP's question...

Then only the last name "Stein" should be separated and stored -- This begs the question -- what are you using the first two words for, and where are you retrieving them?  Wouldn't the better place to get the last word be in the part of the code where you are retrieving the first two words?  If so, then this all becomes a moot point, and you would simply get the last word when you are parsing the entire name.  Then ideally it would be in some sort of a struct Ex: struct Author { std::string first_name, middle_name, last_name; };, and then store the entire name in the struct.

I don't think you understand what streams are used for.
You already have a std::string, just use its interface: rfind and substr.
std::string get_last_name(const std::string& full_name)
{
    auto last_word_pos = full_name.rfind(' ') + 1;
    return full_name.substr(last_word_pos);
}

Demo
This assumes that the last name is always found after the last space, and that it does not itself contain a space.
Also note that the "last element" of a string is just a character, not a word.

Words are not "elements" of a string stream. It is only the way how extraction works, that it stops at blanks, that lets you extract words. And you can just do that:
std::string get_last_name (const std::string& full_name)
{
    std::stringstream stream(full_name);
    std::string word;
    while(stream >> word);
    return word;
}

However, this is only for illustration, following your approach. As mentioned in comments, it is somewhat pointless to construct the string stream only to extract the string and you can use rfind and substr to first find the last occurence of the blank and construct the proper substring.
